# Concurrently reading Postgres logical replication slots

Tags: postgresql, replication, cdc, logical-replication

PeerDB, a recently launched Postgres data-movement platform, does few performance optimizations on CDC capture in postgres. From the docs, One of them is parallel reading of postgresql logical replication slots.

It is mentioned in the [discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=36898413),

> Postgres enables you to read a single slot concurrently across 2 connections using 2 separate publications - each publication filters a set of tables

Can a single slot be consumed by two publications as it is specified?
To my knowledge, an individual walsender - apply process pair is created when logical decoding is established between two servers using an exclusive replication slot.

To check this, I tried to execute the following commands,
In provider,

```
CREATE TABLE c1 (a int, b float, c text);
CREATE table c2 (like c1);
CREATE PUBLICATION c_pub for table c1;
CREATE PUBLICATION c_pub2 for table c2;
```

In subscriber, two subscriptions are created with with a single replication slot.

```
CREATE TABLE c1 (a int, b float, c text);
CREATE table c2 (like c1);
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION c_sub CONNECTION 'host=localhost port=8999 user=user_test dbname=postgres' publication c_pub;
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION c_sub2 CONNECTION 'host=localhost port=8999 user=user_test dbname=postgres' publication c_pub2 with (create_slot = false, slot_name = 'c_sub');
```

When the second subscription is created, the following error is thrown,

> ERROR:  could not start WAL streaming: ERROR:  replication slot
> "c_sub" is active for PID 55222

Once the subscription `c_sub` is dropped, the second subscription `c_sub2` is able to stream the changes.

PG Version used : 11.4

Can someone throw light on the `concurrent reading` of a replication slot?

Comment: As far as I know, and as confirmed by some tests I've conducted, it's impossible to concurrently consume data from the same replication slot. Each replication slot can have only one consumer at a time.